# Java Concurrent Exception when using copy of lists

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following code in my class:

```
private static LinkedList<MyObject> myList = 
                new LinkedList<MyObject>();

public static void doEventStuff(String user, String event){
        LinkedList<MyObject> copy;
        synchronized (myList) {
            copy = new LinkedList<>(myList);
        }
        for (MyObject o : copy) {
             ... do something with objects o
        }

}

public static void removeObject(MyObject o) {
        synchronized (myList) {
            myList.remove(o);
        }
        o.doCleanup();
    }

public static void terminate() {
        synchronized (myList) {
            for (MyObject o : myList) {
                o.doCleanup();
            }

            myList.clear();
        }

    }

public static List<MyObject> getMyObjectsCopy() {
        synchronized (myList) {
            return new LinkedList<>(myList);
        }
    }
```

My problem is a ConcurrentModificationException when calling terminate() , specifically when iterating "for (MyObject o : myList) ".

The list myList is not passed around and can only be accessed through the static methods.
Also: the method MyObject.doCleanup() ca trigger events where the method "removeObject(MyObject)" can be called, when doing the iteration inside terminate() mthod , but since all the methods synchronize 
on "myList", I didn't believe a concurrency exception can happen.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: If it is possible for an object to be removed from the list, use an iterator instead of the for loop. Removing an object during a for loop like that can cause that exception.

Comment: There's some modification to `myList` that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2):

`ConcurrentModificationException` also happens if the list was modified while iterating over it using a 'foreach' loop. `synchronize` will help avoid other threads from accessing your list, but your issue is not due to thread-concurrency. If you want to delete (from the same thread) while iterating over the list, you must use an `iterator` and call `iterator.remove()`.

Comment: How will iteration.remove helps with removing from non thread safe collection in multithreaded environment? ConcurrentModificationException itself is mostly an issue with iterators.

Comment: Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing

Comment: @DmitrySpikhalskiy updated my answer. Synchronize helps with CME but not in this case.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer... The events that triggered in the doCleanup() method did not arrive (and did not call methods from my external callbacks) on a separate thread, do synchronizing in the removeObject(...) method didn't actually do anything...

Answer (score 2):

This is not `multi-threading` issue per se, if you remove an object from the list in a `foreach` loop you will get `ConcurrentModificationException`.
And by the way, you can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)  instead

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
for (MyObject o : myList) {
    o.doCleanup(o);
}
```

You call code, which internally calls removeObject() method. In this call we make myList.remove(o), which will change a list, as a result, it works like:

```
for (MyObject o : myList) {
    myList.remove();
}
```

So, it's not a concurrency issue, it's just modification of collection in forEach loop over this collection. I think the best solution for this situation is to avoid removing from myList in doCleanup() code, it looks like lack of design.
Other possible solution - another doCleanup() method version which doesn't throw an event which cause removal from collection - you already do myList.clear().
Or rewrite removeObject() method like:

```
public static void removeObject(MyObject o) {
    synchronized (myList) {
        for (Iterator<MyObject> it = myList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            MyObject o1 = it.next();
            if (o1.equals(o)) {
               it.remove();
            }
        }            
    }
    o.doCleanup();
}
```

like @geert3 recommends in his answer as far as I understand, but motivation in this answer is not fully clear for me.

But I don't like last solution - it looks like a hack for design problem because in this global collection maintaining code we call doCleanup() on deleted object which should call one more removeObject() inside event handler - I think it will be better to remove this "recursion".